# Exclude Weekends and get time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to exclude weekends in this case and get difference of time only between given dates, below is the scenario.

```
declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
select @d1 = '2017-08-10 19:51:01.000',  @d2 = '2017-08-16 17:52:14.000'

select 
    Convert(varchar(5),datediff(s, @d1, @d2)/3600 - (datediff(wk, @d1, @d2) * 2) -
       case when datepart(dw, @d1) = 1 then 24 else 0 end + 
       case when datepart(dw, @d2) = 1 then 24 else 0 end )
         +':'+
         convert(Varchar(5),datediff(s, @d1, @d2)%3600/60  - (datediff(wk, @d1, @d2) * 2) -
       case when datepart(dw, @d1) = 1 then 24 else 0 end +
       case when datepart(dw, @d2) = 1 then 24 else 0 end)
          +':'+
         convert(Varchar(5),datediff(s, @d1, @d2)%60 - (datediff(wk, @d1, @d2) * 2) -
       case when datepart(dw, @d1) = 1 then 24 else 0 end +
      case when datepart(dw, @d2) = 1 then 24 else 0 end
         ) as hrs
```

Comment: By "weekend", did you really mean "non-work days"? Because those are not the same thing. And since natural disasters are in the news, consider that even "standard" work days might not actually be "worked". How do you solve this? Search the internet for "calendar table".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to find the first Monday (if we say that "weekends" means Saturdays and Sundays) on or after @d1 and last Monday before @d2. This is the number of whole weeks. So the hours in one whole week are 120 (5 days * 24 hours). Then we will add the hours after this last Monday till @d2. A simple case by the day of week of @d2 will allow you to take care of the weekend in this last week. Similarly, we will count the hours between @d1 and before the first Monday.

```
declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
select @d1 = '2017-08-10 19:51:01.000',  @d2 = '2017-08-16 17:52:14.000'

declare @StartOfFirstWeekAfterStartDate date = cast(dateadd(day, case datepart(weekday, @d1)
    when 1 /* Sunday */ then -6
    when 2 /* Monday */ then 0
    when 3 /* Tuesday */ then 6
    when 4 /* Wendsday */ then 5
    when 5 /* Thursday */ then 4
    when 6 /* Friday */ then 3
    when 7 /* Saturday */ then 2
    end, @d1) as date),
    @StartOfLastWeekBeforeEndDate date = cast(dateadd(day, case datepart(weekday, @d2)
    when 1 /* Sunday */ then -6
    when 2 /* Monday */ then 0
    when 3 /* Tuesday */ then -1
    when 4 /* Wendsday */ then -2
    when 5 /* Thursday */ then -3
    when 6 /* Friday */ then -4
    when 7 /* Saturday */ then -5
    end, @d2) as date)

declare @NumberOfWorkdays int = datediff(week, @StartOfFirstWeekAfterStartDate, @StartOfLastWeekBeforeEndDate) * 5

declare @HoursWeekBefore int = case datepart(weekday, @d1)
    when 1 /* Sunday */ then 0
    when 2 /* Monday */ then 5 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 3 /* Tuesday */ then 4 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 4 /* Wendsday */ then 3 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 5 /* Thursday */ then 2 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 6 /* Friday */ then 1 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 7 /* Saturday */ then 0
    end

declare @HoursWeekAfter int = case datepart(weekday, @d2)
    when 1 /* Sunday */ then 5 * 24
    when 2 /* Monday */ then 0 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
    when 3 /* Tuesday */ then 1 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
    when 4 /* Wendsday */ then 2 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
    when 5 /* Thursday */ then 3 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
    when 6 /* Friday */ then 4 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
    when 7 /* Saturday */ then 5 * 24
    end

declare @HoursDiff int = @HoursWeekBefore + @NumberOfWorkdays * 24 + @HoursWeekAfter

select
    @StartOfFirstWeekAfterStartDate,
    datepart(WEEKDAY, @StartOfFirstWeekAfterStartDate), -- Should always be Monday
    @StartOfLastWeekBeforeEndDate,
    datepart(WEEKDAY, @StartOfLastWeekBeforeEndDate), -- Should always be Monday
    @NumberOfWorkdays,
    datediff(week, @StartOfFirstWeekAfterStartDate, @StartOfLastWeekBeforeEndDate),
    @HoursWeekBefore,
    @HoursWeekAfter,
    @HoursDiff
```

The code above is suitable for sp/udf use. If we put all these calculations in a single expression, it will become this:

```
declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
select @d1 = '2017-08-10 19:51:01.000',  @d2 = '2017-08-16 17:52:14.000'

select case datepart(weekday, @d1)
    when 1 /* Sunday */ then 0
    when 2 /* Monday */ then 5 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 3 /* Tuesday */ then 4 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 4 /* Wendsday */ then 3 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 5 /* Thursday */ then 2 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 6 /* Friday */ then 1 * 24 - datepart(hour, @d1)
    when 7 /* Saturday */ then 0
    end /* @HoursWeekBefore */
    + 
    datediff(week, 
        cast(dateadd(day, case datepart(weekday, @d1)
            when 1 /* Sunday */ then -6
            when 2 /* Monday */ then 0
            when 3 /* Tuesday */ then 6
            when 4 /* Wendsday */ then 5
            when 5 /* Thursday */ then 4
            when 6 /* Friday */ then 3
            when 7 /* Saturday */ then 2
            end, @d1) as date) /* @StartOfFirstWeekAfterStartDate */,
        cast(dateadd(day, case datepart(weekday, @d2)
            when 1 /* Sunday */ then -6
            when 2 /* Monday */ then 0
            when 3 /* Tuesday */ then -1
            when 4 /* Wendsday */ then -2
            when 5 /* Thursday */ then -3
            when 6 /* Friday */ then -4
            when 7 /* Saturday */ then -5
            end, @d2) as date) /* @StartOfLastWeekBeforeEndDate */) * 5 /* @NumberOfWorkdays */ * 24 
    + 
    case datepart(weekday, @d2)
        when 1 /* Sunday */ then 5 * 24
        when 2 /* Monday */ then 0 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
        when 3 /* Tuesday */ then 1 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
        when 4 /* Wendsday */ then 2 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
        when 5 /* Thursday */ then 3 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
        when 6 /* Friday */ then 4 * 24 + datepart(hour, @d2)
        when 7 /* Saturday */ then 5 * 24
        end /* @HoursWeekAfter */
```

Please, not that the above calculation depends on [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql) setting. I wrote it with the assumption that Sunday is the first day of week (i.e. datepart(weekday, @Moday) will return 2). If this is not the case, you should adjust the offsets in the case statements.
Also I didn't handles the minutes in these times, so the hours calculation is a bit rough. If this is an issue, you may use the above method to calculate the number of minutes between @d1 and @d2 and to divide this by 60.

Comment: Thank you Andrey Nikolov for helping me out in this regard, however Saturday is the first day of the week. is it possible to modify accordingly and help me out. I am new at these coding and confusing me hence requesting for modification of codes.

Comment: You should either add **set DATEFIRST 7** at the top of this query (to change the first day of the week to be Sunday) or change the numbers in the case statements, where **datepart(weekday)** is used, to be 2 for Sunday, 3 for Monday, 4 for Tuesday, 5 for Wednesday, 6 for Thursday, 7 for Friday and 1 for Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

```
create function DateDiffWeekends(@a date, @b date)
returns int as
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result int
SELECT @Result = DateDiff(dd,@a,@b) 
               - DateDiff(ww,@a,@b)*2 
               - case DatePart(dw,@a) when 1 then 1 else 0 end 
               - case DatePart(dw,@b) when 7 then 1 else 0 end 
RETURN @Result
End
```

This is (similar to) a function that I'm using a production environment. I'll break down what each of the four formulas in the `SELECT @Result` area are doing.

```
DateDiff(dd,@a,@b)
```

This is simply finding the number of days between two dates. Classic DateDiff.

```
- DateDiff(ww,@a,@b)*2
```

This finds the number of weeks between the two days, and multiplies it by two. The reason that this works is because it's counting the number of week breaks, not the number of "7 day segments." For instance, if I picked dates of Friday and the following Monday, `DateDiff(ww,$Saturday,$Monday)` would return 1 week, even though they're only technically 2 days apart.

```
- case DatePart(dw,@a) when 1 then 1 else 0 end
```

If you pick a start date of Sunday, then you're going to need to take one more day off of the result. If your start day is Saturday, then it's going to be in a different week, so the previous statement will take care of it.

```
- case DatePart(dw,@b) when 7 then 1 else 0 end
```

If you pick an end date of Saturday, then you're also going to need to take one day off of the result. If your end day is Sunday, it's going to, again, be in a different week.

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57c48/11/0) if you want to test/play with it.

EDIT: I just noticed that you've also asked for time. I'm going to leave this answer here, in case it's useful to someone else, but it might not work in your case.