# How can I exclude some days when using DATEDIFF function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff, date-difference

My simple select statement looks like this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, TTHI_CREATED_ON, GETDATE()) FROM TT_TAPE_ISSUE_HD
```

It works perfectly. I need to exclude **Thursday** & **Friday** and display the number of days different. How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: What do yuo mean `I need to exclude Thursday & Friday and display the number of days different`? Do you want to exclude  `GETDATE()` or `TTHI_CREATED_ON`?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Hi, I mean when passing 2 dates in **DATEDIFF** function, it should not count Thursday and Friday.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765962/calculating-days-to-excluding-weekends-monday-to-friday-in-sql-server possible duplicate of

Comment: Check this question, it should help.
[Exclude Weekends and get time in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345662/exclude-weekends-and-get-time-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to avoid 2 days from a week which is Thursday & Friday you can use the below query

```
 SELECT
  (DATEDIFF(dd, TTHI_CREATED_ON,  GETDATE()) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, TTHI_CREATED_ON,  GETDATE()) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, TTHI_CREATED_ON) = 'Thursday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, TTHI_CREATED_ON) = 'Friday ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Tank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link it will provide you more idea,

[How to calculate the number of "Tuesdays" between two dates in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563069/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-tuesdays-between-two-dates-in-tsql)

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY, TTHI_CREATED_ON, GETDATE())-
(datediff(day, -4, GETDATE())/7-datediff(day, -3, TTHI_CREATED_ON)/7 
  + datediff(day, -4, GETDATE())/7-datediff(day, -2, TTHI_CREATED_ON)/7 )
  FROM TT_TAPE_ISSUE_HD
```